# How to assign multiple variables depending on a condition

Tags: javascript

I want to assign multiple variables depending on a condition, but it keeps getting the error `'SyntaxError: Identifier 'end' has already been declared'`

Both functions returns a timestamp.

My previous code was just:

```
let [start, end] = getPeriod(period)
```

But now I need to assign depending on a condition

```
let [start, end] = [null,null];

  if(period != 'custom') {
    [start, end] = getPeriod(period)
  } else {
    [start, end] = getCustomPeriod(startDate, endDate);
  }
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggests?

Comment: What does `getPeriod()` do? Is really `end` variable already defined?

Comment: It's says `end` is already defined but not for `start`. So, `end` is probably defined somewhere before

Comment: @adiga isn't `end` a JavaScript reservated word?

Comment: The code is working on my side, it must be the code before the one you posted.

Comment: @k3llydev don't think so

Comment: Also, if both functions are returning a timestamp, why are you destructuring?

Comment: I changed the variable name and it's working, but I couldn't find where I declared 'end' before :( Anyway, thank u guys so much!

Comment: @PauloVítor You can use search of your editor for it. Don't forget to accept correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

The error means the variable `end` is already declared elsewhere in your code, search for it or rename the variable in your new piece of code.

Also, you could use a ternary to make this a one-liner:

```
const [ start, end ] = (period !== 'custom') ? getPeriod(period) : getCustomPeriod(startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: @adiga you're right, it wasn't very clear, I've re-ordered my answer to put the pertinent information first.